# Как правильно облегчить запрос с множеством join?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть вот такой вот запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM file file1
  LEFT JOIN file file2 ON ((((file2.transaction_code)::text = '10'::text) AND ((file1.uid)::text = (file2.uid)::text)))
  LEFT JOIN file file3 ON (((((file3.transaction_code)::text = '02'::text) AND ((file1.uid)::text = (file3.uid)::text)) AND (file3.send_date > file1.send_date)))
  LEFT JOIN file file4 ON (((((file4.transaction_code)::text = '04'::text) AND ((file1.uid)::text = (file4.uid)::text)) AND (file4.send_date > file1.send_date)))
  LEFT JOIN file file5 ON (((((file5.transaction_code)::text = '07'::text) AND ((file1.uid)::text = (file5.uid)::text)) AND (file5.send_date > file1.send_date)))
  LEFT JOIN file file6 ON ((((((file6.turn_code)::text = '07'::text) AND ((file1.uid)::text = (file6.uid)::text)) AND (file6.complete = true)) AND (file6.send_date > file1.send_date)))
  LEFT JOIN error ON (((file1.uid)::text = (error.uid)::text))
WHERE  (((file1.turn_code)::text = '01'::text) AND ((file1.transaction_code)::text = '01'::text));
```

Работает такое крайне медленно, надо с этим что-то делать. Первое, что пришло в голову - это заменить `JOIN` на `OR` где можно. Получилось такая неработающая штука:

```
SELECT *
FROM file
WHERE
  ((((file.transaction_code)::text = '10'::text) AND ((file.uid)::text = (file.uid)::text))
  OR ((((file.transaction_code)::text = '02'::text) AND ((file.uid)::text = (file.uid)::text)) AND (file.send_date > file.send_date))
  OR ((((file.transaction_code)::text = '04'::text) AND ((file.uid)::text = (file.uid)::text)) AND (file.send_date > file.send_date))
  OR ((((file.transaction_code)::text = '07'::text) AND ((file.uid)::text = (file.uid)::text)) AND (file.send_date > file.send_date))
  OR (((((file.turn_code)::text = '07'::text) AND ((file.uid)::text = (file.uid)::text)) AND (file.complete = true)) AND (file.send_date > file.send_date)))
  AND  (((file.turn_code)::text = '01'::text) AND ((file.transaction_code)::text = '01'::text));
```

Такая штука загружается на много дольше и выводит неверный результат. Что делать ?

Comment: Почему вопрос про производительность запроса без DDL и без `explain (analyze,buffers)`? И что вообще сделать хотите?

Comment: Я понимаю ваше недовольство, но этот вопрос больше теоретический. Что в принципе можно сделать с кучей `join`'ов на одну и ту же таблицу ?

Comment: Посмотреть explain. Подумать. Проставить индексы, сделать analyze, посмотреть explain. Или в другом направлении поехать: осмыслить потребный результат и понять, что надо получить от запроса. Соответственно этому переписать запрос полностью.

Comment: @faoxis Все таки надо с плана начинать ... я вот например не понимаю зачем такие `(file1.uid)::text = (file2.uid)::text)` сложности. Эти поля невозможно что ли сравнивать без приведения типа ? Ведь приведение типа не дает оптимизатору использовать индекс. И кстати, а есть ли вообще индекс

Comment: И надо все таки видеть структуру изначальной таблицы и понимать какие данные ожидаются на выходе под этой `*`. Первое что приходит в голову - `group by uid` и вытягивание нужных полей по горизонтали какими нибудь `max(case transaction_code when 10 then xx end)`

Comment: А, там еще даты как то участвуют подозреваю что понадобится `lag()` в общем не видя данных и не понимая чего вы хотите из них получить ответить на ваш вопрос невозможно. А в варианте с  OR вообще какой то бред. те условия бесполезны, там везде `X>X`, чего быть не может

Comment: @Mike а можно ссылку на страницу с документацией, где говорится, что приведения типов отменяют поиск по индексу ?

Comment: В документации это обычно не пишут. Хотя может и пишут, но где, я не знаю. Мне об этом говорит логика и опыт общения с другими СУБД. Поиск по двоичному дереву при не совпадающем формате ключа невозможен. Да и документация не нужна вообще для таких вещей. только что провел тест: в postgresql 9.5.0 создал таблицу из 1 колонки (X int not null primary key), вставил в нее 100к записей (из generate_series). План выполнения для `select * from tab where X=500` показывает работу по первичному ключу стоимость 8.31. `select * from tab where X::text='500'` дает полный перебор таблицы и стоимость 2193